# Want to place a QPushButton onto a GraphicView... but no button is displayed?

Tags: c++, qt

Want to place a QPushButton onto a GraphicView... but no button is displayed?

I am creating a new window for each plot.  On each plot I want to put some buttons for functionality.  I don't know if I should put the view on another type of window... if so how?  thx

```
        QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();

        QPixmap image;
        image.load(fileInfo.filePath(), 0);
        scene->addPixmap(image);
        scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());

        QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
        view->setScene(scene);
        view->setWindowTitle(QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(QGraphicsView, "My Plot"));
        view->resize(1000, 1000);
        view->show();

        QPushButton *m_button6 = new QPushButton("ok", view);
        m_button6->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(50, 50), QSize(50, 50)));
        connect(m_button6, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(handleButton5()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it around QGraphicsWidget.

```
QGraphicsWidget *pBtn = scene->addWidget(m_button6);  
scene->addItem(pBtn)
```

oh! don't forget:

```
m_button6->show();
```

widgets are hidden by default!

Comment: ERROR: "'addWidget' was not declared in this scope".  However I can do scene->addWidget(m_button6), but that won't display the button.